# typescript regex match even if one part matches

Tags: regex, typescript

```
<<EOH
   bind_port:   {[ env "NOMAD_PORT_db" ]}
   scratch_dir: {[ env "NOMAD_TASK_DIR" ]}
   node_id:     {[ key "node.unique.id" ]}
   service_key: {[ key "service/my-key" ]}
EOH
```

i have some part of the form code where i accept user input data like above. I have one validation to make. User should not call `{{ key .... }}` instead they should use `{{ env .... }}`.

```
{\[\s+?key\s+?".+?"\s+?\]}
```

This is the regex that i came up with, it should get even one match. On the type script side how do i add this to my code. where i can do something like

1. regex match
2. atleast one match found
3. return
4. no match found
5. pass.

I tried this on the code side.

```
 const matches = value.matchAll(new RegExp('{[s+?keys+?".+?"s+?]}', "g"));
            for (const match of matches) {
              console.log(match);
              return createError({ message: "use {[ env .. ]} instead of {[ key .. ]}" });
            }
```

doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegExp#test` and use a tuned regex like

```js
/{\[\s*key\s*"[^"]*"\s*]}/
```

Note the absence of `g` flag, and lazy quantifiers are replaced with greedy ones for better performance. `\s+?` matches at least one whitespace, but I assume the whitespace can also be absent, so I turned these into `\s*` (zero or more whitespaces).

Since it is a regex that matches an unwelcome pattern, the `RegExp#test` result must be negated with `!` before the function invocation.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = `bind_port:   {[ env "NOMAD_PORT_db" ]}
scratch_dir: {[ env "NOMAD_TASK_DIR" ]}
node_id:     {[ key "node.unique.id" ]}
service_key: {[ key "service/my-key" ]}`;
const re = /{\[\s*key\s*"[^"]*"\s*]}/;
if (!re.test(text)) {
    console.log("Valid!"); // Return true here if you use it in a function
} else {
    console.log("use {[ env .. ]} instead of {[ key .. ]}");
}
```